# Typoscript condition && condition not working?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, browser-detection

This is my (shortened) code:

```
lib.nav = COA
lib.nav {
  50 = HMENU
  50 { 
      [ ... ]
  wrap = <nav>|</nav> 
  }
}

[browser = msie] && [version = <9]
lib.nav.50.wrap = <div id="nav">|</div> 
[global]
```

What I know (did):

- `[browser = msie]` alone works but for all IE (I need less than 9)
- I installed the `conditions` extension
- I searched for it but couldn't find anything that would fit **exactly** my problem

What I need is either a TS snippet that would work or maybe a workaround.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is quite old, but I've just solved similar problem. In my case condition failed because I used it inside a block like this:

```
config {
    # htmlTag_setParams, adding language and some classes for the Foundation framework
    [browser = msie] && [version =< 9]
    htmlTag_setParams = lang="{$config.language}" class="no-js lt-ie9"
    [else]
    htmlTag_setParams = lang="{$config.language}" class="no-js"
    [global]
}
```

as soon as I rewritten it as

```
# htmlTag_setParams, adding language and some classes for the Foundation framework
[browser = msie] && [version =< 9]
config.htmlTag_setParams = lang="{$config.language}" class="no-js lt-ie9"
[else]
config.htmlTag_setParams = lang="{$config.language}" class="no-js"
[global]
```

it started working as expected

P.S. I'm using Typo3 v6.1

Comment: Yes, conditions cannot be used inside blocks. Although this wasn't the case for MrRap (because some of the conditions worked for him) it might be useful info for other people.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition looks correct.

So, perhaps you have an different error? Try to separate your problems via testing the condition without side-effects. Create a new page, create a new ts-template and put this code into it:

```
page >
page = PAGE
page.typeNum = 0
page.10 = TEXT
[browser = msie] && [version = <9]
page.10.value = Condition is meet
[else]
page.10.value = Condition is not meet
[global]
```

Now open this page in your browser. Now you can adjust your Conditions. If everything works, the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

If your scripts are stored and nested in the file-system (e.g. with INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT), try to insert your condition directly in your typo3 back-end, in the [setup field of your main template](http://docs.typo3.org/TYPO3/GettingStartedTutorial/Templates/TheSetupField/Index.html).

```
#your previously included file
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/_TypoScript/myTyposcriptFile.ts">

#your condition
page >
page = PAGE
page.typeNum = 0
page.10 = TEXT
[browser = msie] && [version = <9]
page.10.value = Condition is meet
[else]
page.10.value = Condition is not meet
[global]
```

You can also check if your conditions are working as expected by using the "condition" function at the bottom of the [TypoScript Object Browser](http://docs.typo3.org/TYPO3/GettingStartedTutorial/Templates/TheObjectBrowser/Index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the [browser = msie] isn't working anymore (T3 4.5+). The test setup always shows that the condition is not meet even though I'm watching in Internet Explorer.